# What is the path to a phar file

Tags: php, phar

I have created a phar file of my framework. The way you run cron-jobs in the framework is by calling executing the pharfile on the command line:

```
php path/to/archive.phar cron -r /path/to/site
```

The bootstrap file in the archive used to compare the path of **_*FILE*_** with the resolved path of the executed command to determine that it had been executed directly.

The question is: Is it possible to get the filename of the phar-file from within the phar file, and how?

That is: what is the alternative to **_*FILE*_** in phar-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it:

```
<?php
$a = Phar::running(); // $a is "phar:///path/to/my.phar"
```

As in [docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/phar.running.php).

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of research on the matter and it seems it is impossible without incurring too much overhead.

The only plausible way I've found is by opening the "suspect" gotten from $argv[0] and check by inspecting the contents - however, that involves a lot of extra disk IO.